# Given $f'(x)=(2x/2\sqrt{x^2+2})-3$, what are the critical points?

Tags: calculus

I've been given a function
$$y=\sqrt{2+x^2}-3x$$

and I need to find the absolute minimum and maximum between $[5,6]$. I've already found (assuming I did it right) the derivative of y to be
$$f'(x)=\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+2}}-3$$

Now I need to find the critical values, but I'm not sure if I did something wrong or if I don't know how to do it given this problem. I've come up to a roadblock because I'm dealing with a square root, and I can't get all the x variables to one side, aside from having
$$\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+2}}=3$$ or $$x=3\sqrt{x^2+2}$$

Can somebody point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: it mut be "minus 3" in the derivative...

Comment: Sorry - I had it written down right but copied it incorrectly here. I fixed it.

Comment: You also lost the factor of 3, as in $x = 3\sqrt{x^2+2}$

Comment: You should have x = 3 sqrt[x^2 + 2], which should lead to x = (3/2)i (imaginary result). Can you find your errors (for example the 2 in the numerator and the one outside the sqrt should not be there). So, what if you put the 3 back in, square both sides and solve for x? Is that enough of a hint? Of course, what does an imaginary result mean in this context?

Comment: Simply square both sides, as you thought to do, but now with the corrected derivation...

Comment: So then $\forall x\in \mathbb{R},f'(x)\neq 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little manipulation, we reach
$$x=3\sqrt{2+x^2}.$$
A reasonable thing to do is to square both sides.
We reach $x^2=18+9x^2$.

It is easy to see that this equation has no real solution. so there are no critical points.

Thus the max and min occur at the endpoints. Substitute $5$ and $6$ to find out which is which. Actually, since $f'(x)$ is negative, we know the max is at $5$ and the min is at $6$.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see the function's derivative doesn't vanish where you want (in fact, it vanishes nowhere). Most probably what was meant is to check the *extreme points* of the given interval, as they are **always** extreme points of a function defined on a finite interval *per definition*, thus:

$$f(5)=\sqrt{2+25}-3\cdot 5=\sqrt{27}-15$$

$$f(6)=\sqrt{2+36}-3\cdot 6=\sqrt{38}-18$$

and since $\,f'(x)<0\,$, we get that $\,(5,f(5))\,$ is a local maximum, and $\,(6,f(6))\,$ is a local minimum. Please note that the extreme points of a function in a finite interval are *always* one-sided local extreme.